# Need to make time EST on GMT server

Tags: php, date, time

I need to change the time from GMT to EST, here is the code I am using

```
$currenttime = date(H . ":" . i);
```

I am using PHP 4.

Tried a couple of things but nothing will work due to the PHP 4 bit, any help appreciated.

Comment: What is `H . ':' . i`?? The format string is just that, a string: `"H:i"`.

Comment: I have no problem with the original code, that works other than it showing he server time which is GMT and I want it to be EST.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i get the gmt time in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851574/how-do-i-get-the-gmt-time-in-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing Default TimeZone in Php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709458/changing-default-timezone-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this before you do any time computation   `date_default_timezone_set('EST');`

Also your dateformat is wrong, this is how you do it: `$currenttime = date("H:i");`

Comment: The date default bit doesnt work on php 4. I was hoping for a -5 hours or something

Comment: Best you check this guy out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709458/changing-default-timezone-in-php